# Futura font not rendering in firefox

Tags: wordpress, fonts, font-face, generator

I have a problem with displaying specific futura fonts on firefox.

Actually I use 5 futura fonts and I got problem with one of them:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'FuturaLT-CondensedBold';
            src: url('fonts/futuraltcondensedbold.eot');
            src: url('fonts/futuraltcondensedbold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                     url('fonts/futuraltcondensedbold.woff') format('application/x-font-woff'),
                     url('fonts/futuraltcondensedbold.ttf') format('truetype'),
                     url('fonts/futuraltcondensedbold.svg#futuraltcondensedbold') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
    }
@font-face {
                font-family: 'FuturaLT-Bold';
                src: url('fonts/futuraltbold.eot');
                src: url('fonts/futuraltbold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('fonts/futuraltbold.woff') format('application/x-font-woff'),
                         url('fonts/futuraltbold.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('fonts/futuraltbold.svg#futuraltbold') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
        }

@font-face {
                font-family: 'FuturaBT-LightCondensed';
                src: url('fonts/futura-ltcn-bt-light.eot');
                src: url('fonts/futura-ltcn-bt-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('fonts/futura-ltcn-bt-light.woff') format('application/x-font-woff'),
                         url('fonts/futura-ltcn-bt-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('fonts/futura-ltcn-bt-light.svg#futura-ltcn-bt-light') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
        }
@font-face {
                font-family: 'FuturaBT-Medium';
                src: url('fonts/futuram.eot');
                src: url('fonts/futuram.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('fonts/futuram.woff') format('application/x-font-woff'),
                         url('fonts/futuram.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('fonts/futuram.svg#futuram') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
        }
```

So, I have problem using  font-family: 'FuturaLT-Bold'; in firefox. The others are rendering just fine, but this one it appears as dark gray in firefox inspect element with firebug, like the font doesnt exists at all. The font was coverted by codeandmore font face generator.

I also changed my .httaccess file with following rules:

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

but it didnt helped...

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the css for FuturaLT-Book listed, could be the problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant I have problems with  font-family: 'FuturaLT-Bold'; !

Comment: Gotcha! I'd re-encode that specific font and upload again, it may have become corrupt along the way.